# Processing-NullPointerException when converting string to char

Tags: processing

So I have a set of different strings made if a certain key is pressed using keyPressed(), but some of those strings i want to convert to characters and tried doing so like this:

```
char keyChar = keyChanged.charAt(0);
```

except now i get a nullpointerexpression. if it matters, keyChanged would be a 1 letter string like "r".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid a NullPointerException like this:

```
if (keyChanged != null){   
  char keyChar = keyChanged.charAt(0); 
}
```

Comment: I found a simpler solution but this wouldve worked too i believe!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, It was pretty stupid on my part, I just set the original keyChanged variable as a character instead.